# no mysql option while installing

Tags: 8, installation

I am trying to install Drupal 8 on my PC running Windows 7.
I am using XAMP; MySQL is installed and running properly. Drupal only provides the option for SQLite.

Comment: Did you install the PHP extensions for PHP and PHP PDO? Installing MySQL doesn't mean to install those too.